# Continuity at $+\infty$ for the function defined by $f(0)=\infty$ and $f(x)=1/x$ for $x \in (0,10]$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let the domain of the function $f(x)$ be $[0, 10]$, and its range be the extended real numbers (including +$\infty$ and -$\infty$). Define:

$
   f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       1/x & : 0 < x \leq 10\\
       +\infty & : x = 0
     \end{array}
   \right.
$

Question: why is $f(x)$ not continuous at $0$?

Context: there is a theorem that states a function is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$ iff it can be extended to a continuous function on $[a,b]$. Because $1/x$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,10)$, the extension function $f(x)$ defined above must not be continuous.

Comment: In the extended real numbers, this limit exists $\lim_{x \to 0} 1/x = +\infty$. So I think the usual $\epsilon-\delta$ definition applies only to real limits, not infinite limits - can someone confirm this is true? This is similar to the definition of infinite limits for monotone sequences that blow up.

Comment: I am not sure how familiar you are with topology, but topology gives a way to generalize what it means for a function to be continuous, outside of the setting where you would use the $\epsilon\delta$ definitions which only makes sense in metric spaces. Of course the theorems you learn in analysis might not have analogues outside of metric spaces (or maybe even outside of $\mathbb{R}$) so won't hold in general topological spaces.

Answer (score 3):

There is a sense in which this is continuous, using the "obvious" topology that one would get with adding $\infty$, in particular $(r,\infty]$ would be open (and you consider the topology generated by the standard topology plus these new "balls" around $\infty$). So $f(0)=\infty$, and we may consider an open ball at $\infty$, say $(r,\infty]$. Well $f^{-1}(r,\infty] = [0,1/r) \cap [0,10]$ which is open.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity. If $x=0$ and you want $\epsilon = 1$ what will $\delta$ be? $\epsilon-\delta$ definition is applicable to any metric space, not only the real line.

The confusion is arising from $lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \infty$. This is a statement very different from $lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = 1$, for example. In the former case there is no converging going on. The values of $f(x)$ never get particularly close to $\infty$. This is a notation only used for real numbers. Using the topological definition of a limit we would say that $lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: Karolis Juodelė, could you take a look at the comment under the question?

Comment: @FreshAir, answer updated

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f$ was continuous at zero. Then there exists some $\delta>0$
s.t. $0<\left|x-0\right|=\left|x\right|<\delta$ implies $\left|f\left(x\right)-\infty\right|<1$.
Spot the contradiction?

Comment: par, I made a comment under the question in this regard.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not you are working with the extended reals, as long as you are using the usual notion of order, $|f(x)-\infty|=|1/x-\infty|=\infty$ (recall that $|x|>0$) which is clearly greater than one.